# Photo filter: What is the name of this filter

Tags: photo-editing, instagram

This is my first post here. I am new to photography. I am amazed with some of the beautiful works people are doing. Equally I have started to love the power of filters. I jus saw the following photo:

[image]

Can some please tell, what is the name of this filter? I wonder If there is any tutorial that helps to recreate this kind of clean nice effect.

Thank you in advance.

Image source: [Link of the image source](http://www.harpersbazaar.com/fashion/street-style/g3957/best-blogger-instagrams/?slide=5)

Comment: Welcome to photo.stackexchange. We hope you enjoy your stay. Please tell us why you think there was a filter used for this image? Can you describe the "effect" you are striving for?

Comment: Thank you. Well probably not, so it can be a good question if any filter was apperantly used. By effect i meant, the white creamy feel.

Comment: I don't think there's a filter used in this image... I'm also not really sure I see the "white creamy feel" here either. Looks like a shot done in bright light with some good contrast and, maybe, a bit of a brightness push. I think Matt has the right of it.

Answer (score 2):

This image is a good example of a "high-key" photo.

Most everything in the shot is white, off-white, pastel, and in bright shade. The exception to indicate there is a full range of tones is the black hair of the subject.

Most every tone in the flat-lit shot is of relatively high luminance. The whites are clean neutrals without a colour cast. Again, the few dark areas show that the photograph is well-exposed. As white laces show against white shoes indicates the image is not over-exposed with the whites clipped.

This image gets its "feel" from the careful choice of subject, lighting, time of day, and composition.